# Can't captured http request of angular2 on chrome develpotool network panel

Tags: angular

Can't capture all HTTP requests on Chrome developer tool network panel,no matter mock data(in-memory-web-api) or real api,success or failed.

Is it due to chrome version?but i test the firefox and it also can not.

So,how can i get http request detail information,like request header and response header

Chrome version:55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)

the detail is here :

consult.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { ConsultListComponent } from './consult-list.component';
import { FrameComponent } from '../frame/frame.component';

import { ConsultService } from './consult.service';

const consultRoutes: Routes=[
  {
    path: 'consults',
    component: FrameComponent,
    //canActivate: [ LoginGuard ],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ConsultListComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(consultRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [ConsultListComponent],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: [ ConsultService ]
})

export class ConsultModule{}
```

consult.service.ts

```js
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()

export class ConsultService {
  test(): void{
    console.log('test service');
  }

  private consultUrl = 'http://192.168.1.208:8088/api/Consult';
  private testUrl = 'https://api.github.com/';

  constructor(private http: Http){
    //this.getConsults();
  }

  getConsults(){
    let body= JSON.stringify({
      "ReplyerId": 1,
      "ReplyerClass": 102,
      "IndexPage": 1
    });
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(options);
    this.http.post(this.consultUrl,body,options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    //return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

consult-list.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ConsultService } from './consult.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'consult-list.component.html'
  //styleUrls: ['frame.component.css']
})

export class ConsultListComponent{
  constructor(private consultService: ConsultService){
    this.consultService.test();
    this.consultService.getConsults();
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you send the request? I don't think in-memory-web-api actually makes HTTP requests.

Comment: Maybe you switched the filter? it has All, XHR, JS, CSS, IMG and some other filters

Comment: If you post screen would be better to see what is wrong

Comment: the real post can't be captures either.like the question shows.

Comment: find the reason . it's due to the InMemoryWebApiModule